# WHM/Cpanel (Centos 6) Installing bugzilla

Tags: cpanel, bugzilla, whm

I have installed bugzilla on my whm/cpanel server but it's redirecting me to 500 error.

My error log contains

```
[Wed Aug 03 00:11:09.525772 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 8054] [client :32814] AH01215: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at index.cgi line 19.: index.cgi

[Wed Aug 03 00:11:09.525716 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 8054] [client :32814] AH01215: Compilation failed in require at index.cgi line 19.: index.cgi

[Wed Aug 03 00:11:09.525655 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 8054] [client :32814] AH01215: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla.pm line 19.: index.cgi

[Wed Aug 03 00:11:09.525538 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 8054] [client :32814] AH01215: Can't locate CGI/Carp.pm in @INC (@INC contains: . lib/x86_64-linux-thread-multi lib /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5) at Bugzilla.pm line 16.: index.cgi
```

I didn't find solution for this by googling. Please anyone help me.

Thanks,

Lanka.

Answer (score 0):

24x7servermanagement server should have some problem with compatibility or not installed all required modules. Is your bugzilla installed successfully after switching server to AWS?

You can find complete installation guide for [bugzilla here..](https://www.bugzilla.org/docs/2.16/html/stepbystep.html)

If you still receive error, provide us error message logs details from new server.

Answer (score -1):

I can see there are some library missing on your server and due to that you are getting all these error. Please check your library status with following command.

```
./checksetup.pl --check-modules
```

Comment: That's not the issue @24x7servermanagement  WHM/Cpanel (centos6) server shows that softwares are installing but it's not actually installing it. I tried command and install software's so many times and moved to AWS server